# Duplicate Foreign Key entries being created on insert - EF Core and Web Api 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

I am currently learning how to work with EF Core with a simple one to many setup, where a `user` can have many `items`. In terms of retrieving the data from the tables, this is fine with some `DTO` models; however, when I try and add a `user` with multiple `items` via Postman, I noticed that for each `item` it had duplicated the user that many times (i.e. a `user` with 3 `items` will create 3 `items` and 3 `users`):

Postman (POST)

```
{
    "username": "xxx",
    "dob": "xxx",
    "location": "xxx",
    "items":[{
        "item": "xxx",
        "category": "xxx",
        "type": "xxx"
        },
        {
        "item": "xxx",
        "category": "xxx",
        "type": "xxx"

        },
        {
        "item": "xxx",
        "category": "xxx",
        "type": "xxx"

        }]
}
```

Context:

```
namespace TestWebApplication.Database
{
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Items> Items { get; set; }

        public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            // erm, nothing here
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(i => i.Items)
                .WithOne(u => u.User);
        }

        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            var entities = from e in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                where e.State == EntityState.Added
                      || e.State == EntityState.Modified
                select e.Entity;

            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                var validationContext = new ValidationContext(entity);
                Validator.ValidateObject(entity, validationContext);
            }

            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("insertuseranditems")]
public ActionResult InsertUserAndItems(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (MyContext myContext = _myContext as MyContext)
        {
            myContext?.Users?.Add(user);
            int changes = myContext.SaveChanges();

            if (changes > 0)
            {
                return Created("User saved", user);
            }
        }
    }

    return Accepted();
}
```

Items:

```
namespace TestWebApplication.Database
{
    public class Items
    {
        [Key]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Users:

```
namespace TestWebApplication.Database
{
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Dob { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Items> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some specific use case that requires writing your own override for the `SaveChanges` method ? From your example, I don't see a need to override it and I imagine it is just making things overly complex. If you want a simple example that can accomplish adding a User with multiple items, then I can provide one.

Comment: I have tried your code and it only created one user with three items.Make sure the foreign key in items is correct.

Comment: @XingZou you mean include the foreign key `public int userid {get; set;}` as well the as `public virtual User User {get; set;}` in the `Items` model?  I did have this in my code but took it out as it didn't make a difference when retrieving the data.

Comment: OK.Maybe you could try in a new mvc project or give a reproducible demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revisited my code and changed my `Items.cs` model to:

```
namespace TestWebApplication.Database
{
    public class Items
    {
        [Key]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("User")] // added this
        public int? UserId { get; set; } // added this

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, when I send the above `json` via Postman, I get multiple items with the same user as a Foreign Key.

The site below seemed to help:

[The ForeignKey Attribute](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/foreignkey-attribute)